# Bitwise operations on a png and bmp give different results? (Same 32 bit ARGB representation)

Tags: java, image-processing

I'm trying to replicate some image filtering software on the Android platform. The desktop version works with bmps but crashes out on png files.

When I come to xOr two pictures (The 32 bit ints of each corresponding pixel) I get very different results for the two pieces of software.

I'm sure my code isn't wrong as it's such a simple task but here it is;

```
const int aMask = 0xFF000000;

int xOrPixels(int p1, int p2) {
    return (aMask | (p1 ^ p2) );
}
```

The definition for the JAI library used by the Java desktop software can be found [here](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai-apidocs/javax/media/jai/operator/XorDescriptor.html) and states;

```
 The destination pixel values are defined by the pseudocode:

 dst[x][y][b] = srcs[0][x][y][b] ^ srcs[1][x][y][b];
```

Where the b is for band (i.e. R,G,B).

Any thoughts? I have a similar problem with AND and OR.

Here is an image with the two source images xOr'd at the bottom on Android using a png. The same file as a bitmap xOr'd gives me a bitmap filled with 0xFFFFFFFF (White), no pixels at all. I checked the binary values of the Android ap and it seems right to me....

[image: Android]

Gav

NB When i say (Same 32 bit ARGB representation) I mean that android allows you to decode a png file to this format. Whilst this might give room for some error (Is png lossless?) I get completely different colours on the output.

Comment: I think your pseudocode is wrong - you're using the same value for both operands of the ^ operator.

Comment: Can you describe how the results are different?  That may help quite a bit...

Comment: The pseudocode is actually from the JAI lib docs (See link). I'll post some pictures in a second so that you can see the differences.

Comment: does XOR behave the same for bytes as it does for ints?

Comment: @kd304: xor is always bitwise in Java, afaik.

Comment: One implementation is in C and one is in Java if it makes any difference?

Comment: Try to XoR with 0 - no op and check the image is the same as the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked a couple of values from your screenshot.

The input pixels:

- Upper left corners, 0xc3cbce^0x293029 = 0xeafbe7
- Nape of the neck, 0xbdb221^0x424dd6 = 0xfffff7

are very similar to the corresponding output pixels.

Looks to me like you are XORing two images that are closely related (inverted in each color channel), so, necessarily, the output is near 0xffffff.

If you were to XOR two dissimilar images, perhaps you will get something more like what you expect.

The question is, why do you want to XOR pixel values?

Answer (score 0):

The png could have the wrong gamma or color space, and it's getting converted on load, affecting the result. Some versions of Photoshop had a bug where they saved pngs with the wrong gamma.

Comment: I'm using GIMP, do you know how I might set this, I'm not really sure what gamma does or is. I'll look it up now. Cheers

Comment: Check to see how the output differs from the input.

Comment: @Nosredna - Using pixel comparison? I was hoping to avoid that. It's easy for my Android implementation which I have verified as taking the xOr of the inputs but I'm not sure what the JAI is doing. I have to give a presentation on this tomorrow and I'd hoped not to have to write any more code :(

Comment: Do a 4x4 image or something and see what's happening.

Comment: Is the dithering on the images happening when they are loaded, before they are XORed together?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inDither

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing prior to the code posted?

[PNG](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2083.txt) is a compressed format, using the deflate algorithm (See Section 5 of [RFC2083](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2083.txt)), so if you're just doing binary reads, you're not looking at actual pixels.